# paypal error processing payment bmcreatebutton

Tags: paypal

I am creating Paypal buttons on the fly for shopping cart processing. I've used Express Checkout with no issues but the client does not want customers to have to complete the billing details on the EC page, using Hosted Payment buttons seems to be the solution.

I create the button using the NVP code sending the following:

```
(
[L_BUTTONVAR0] => business=emailaddress
[L_BUTTONVAR1] => paymentaction=sale
[L_BUTTONVAR2] => currency_code=AUD
[L_BUTTONVAR3] => cancel_return=http://localhost/orders/view/335774
[L_BUTTONVAR4] => notify_url=http://localhost/orders/complete_hostedpaypal/335774
[L_BUTTONVAR5] => return=http://localhost/orders/view/335774
[L_BUTTONVAR6] => invoice=Order #335774
[L_BUTTONVAR7] => subtotal=167.40
[L_BUTTONVAR8] => tax=2
[L_BUTTONVAR9] => shipping=3
[L_BUTTONVAR10] => handling=4
[L_BUTTONVAR11] => template=templateC
[L_BUTTONVAR12] => first_name=TEST
[L_BUTTONVAR13] => last_name=ORDER
[L_BUTTONVAR14] => buyer_email=emailaddress
[L_BUTTONVAR15] => address1=PO Box 2633
[L_BUTTONVAR16] => address2=
[L_BUTTONVAR17] => city=TAREN POINT
[L_BUTTONVAR18] => state=NSW
[L_BUTTONVAR19] => country=AU
[L_BUTTONVAR20] => zip=2229
[L_BUTTONVAR21] => billing_first_name=TEST
[L_BUTTONVAR22] => billing_last_name=ORDER
[L_BUTTONVAR23] => billing_address1=PO Box 2633
[L_BUTTONVAR24] => billing_address2=
[L_BUTTONVAR25] => billing_city=TAREN POINT
[L_BUTTONVAR26] => billing_state=NSW
[L_BUTTONVAR27] => billing_country=AU
[L_BUTTONVAR28] => billing_zip=2229
[L_BUTTONVAR29] => showBillingAddress=false
[L_BUTTONVAR30] => showShippingAddress=false
[L_BUTTONVAR31] => address_override=false
[L_BUTTONVAR32] => bn=AUD
[L_BUTTONVAR33] => lc=AU
[METHOD] => BMCreateButton
[BUTTONCODE] => TOKEN
[BUTTONTYPE] => PAYMENT
[USER] => [api_user]
[PWD] => [api_pwd]
[SIGNATURE] => [api_sig]
[VERSION] => 109.0
```

)

This returns ACK "Success" and the relevant code for the button and links...
When I navigate to the link the Paypal page     https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess?hosted_button_id=HSSS-BPdXvwvPaocw3NpZuxuIhGZuRL1DXlbqFgOo1BvzVYWKoSNjWyYwVilsDmt-QRxxvPmrlA shows:

```
Error Processing Payment
Error Message "This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card."
```

I emailed Paypal Merchant Services but have not had a response for some weeks now. Does anyone have any ideas?

I have upgraded the sandbox to pro.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test using your parameters and generated a payment link, it worked for me(got redirected to templateC page and made a card payment). I used my own test pro account though. Are you seeing the error after you entered card info? If so you may create a fake credit card number on this page, step 4,
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1413&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en

Comment: thanks for testing, however i do not even get to a payment page and therefore do not even get to enter any card information.

Comment: I recreated a new business merchant account and followed the steps in the integration guide and it now works... weird sandbox behaviour

Comment: I guess that your old sandbox business account was not really upgraded to pro although it appears to be, it happens sometimes, just as you said  weird sandbox behavior~